# Azure AD - adaljs...how to use this library?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal.js

I'm using adaljs. Everything seems great...I can log in, log out, wonderful.

Now, after an hour...I load up my app again and! NOT so wonderful. I debug and I see that `adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.isAuthenticated == false` and `adalAuthenticationService.profile == undefined`.

What do I do when I get this? How do I recover?

When do I use these functions and for what?

`acquireToken`
`clearCache`
`clearCacheForResource`
`getCachedToken`
`getResourceForEndpoint`
`getUser`
`logOut`
`logIn`
`logOutInProgress`

Most importantly, **WHY are these not explained** in detail (or even in brief!) on the [adaljs repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)?

Let's turn this into a wiki about adaljs functions and properties. We all want to know what they do, what they are for, and how to use them.

**Edit**

In my app.js, I have this code for handling authentication:

```
if (adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.isAuthenticated && adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.profile) {
                var great = "everything is awesome";
                _ld.extend($scope.user,adalAuthenticationService.userInfo);
                $scope.successFullyLoggedIn($scope.user);
            } else if(!adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.isAuthenticated && !adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.profile) {

                adalAuthenticationService.clearCache();
                adalAuthenticationService.login();
            } else {
                adalAuthenticationService.clearCache();
                adalAuthenticationService.logOut();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The tokens that adal.js gets from AAD expires after every one hour. If you are using angular wrapper then adal will be able to automatically renew the tokens as long as there is a valid user logged in. If you are not using angular wrapper, then application has to take the responsibility of renewing the tokens, that is where the apis will come handy.

I will try to explain what each one of them do:

`acquireToken`: This is one of the main methods. Takes 2 parameters: resourceId and callback. ResourceId is the app id of application on azure portal. Adal first looks into cache to check if there is token present already. If not, it sends a request to AAD to get a new token. It passes the token or the error to the callback, which has a signature like this: callback(err, token).

`clearCache`: delete all items in the browser storage that adal stored. Kind of a fresh start.

`clearCacheForResource`: I am assuming you are using experimental version because this api is not part of released 1.0.12 version. This basically deletes the cache entries for a specific resource id.

`getCachedToken`: Looks into the caceh and returns the token or null for the given resource.

`getResourceForEndpoint`: This is useful when using angular wrapper. This looks into the endpoints mapping that user provided at the time of initializing adal. The purpose of this method is to resolve a url into resourceId which can then be fed to acquireToken method.

`getUser`: current logged in user object or null.

`logOut`: logs out the user, clears cache and redirect the user to postlogoutredirecturi (if specified), otherwise redirects the user to redirecturi.

`login`: logs in the user, creates the user object (which can be accessed using getUser), saves the id token in the cache. It also calls the callback that you have on application level on config object when initializing adal.

`logOutInProgress`: Do you mean loginInProgress? That is just a flag to use internally to see if there is an active login in progress.

Unfortunately, we do not have api guides, that can help people understand our apis better. I will bring this to team's notice. Thanks.

Back to your question: you can use getUser() to get the user object. If it is null, then call logIn() method to log in the user. If user.userName is not null but user.isAuthenticated is false, this means, the token has expired, call acquireToken method and pass clientId of the application to renew the token. Also, you want to check adalAuthenticationService.usernInfo.profile instead of adalAuthenticationService.profile.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. You said "If you are using angular wrapper then adal will be able to automatically renew the tokens as long as there is a valid user logged in". I am using the angular adal wrapper but there isn't any renewal. Every hour it still expires. Check my edit for details on how I handle the authentication...am I doing something incorrectly here?

Comment: When you say, "after an hour...I load up my app again", do you re-open the browser? If you have not checked "remember me" or "keep me signed in" checkbox, you will have to login again. Also, what happens on loading up again? Do you see any errors? Or user gets logged out?

Comment: You can modify your second if check to something like this:
`else if(!adalAuthenticationService.userInfo && !adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {`

Comment: If I open the browser after an hour and try to go to the app again, my app will see that user is no longer authenticated and clear the cache and perform "logout" which makes the user log in again. Maybe I shouldn't do that? What should the app do if it sees user is no longer authenticated (because the token is expired)? And what's the right way to check if the token is expired? Should I just check to see if user is authenticated?

Comment: Your else if statement will get an error is there is no userInfo. If there is no userInfo then it can't check isAuthenticated.